# Find the object from its shadows

Tags: visual, three-dimensional

A 3D object is suspended in the air and it casts shadows on each orthogonal plane. The shadows are in the form of a circle, triangle and square, as shown in the diagram below. What is the shape of the mystery object?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the object we seek is solid all the way through (in the same way as a cube, tetrahedron or sphere would be), this mystery object can be created by...

> ...intersecting a cylinder with a triangular prism.
>
>  [image: Intersecting a cylinder and triangular prism]
>
>  The resulting object looks like this:
>
>  [image: The object itself]
>  <sub>(Images taken from [missouristate.edu](http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/adv79.html)).</sub>
>
>  The circular shadow is formed by shining a light directly along the cylindrical component, the triangular shadow is formed by light hitting the end of the triangular prism head-on, and the square shadow is formed by light hitting the triangular prism from the side.

A nice image showing the shadow effect in action can be seen here:

> [image]
>  <sub>*[Source](https://68.media.tumblr.com/af645c0a82d297e425e6bd812e67259a/tumblr_inline_nfuqvg7TAj1qaf1g3.png)*.</sub>

Jaap Scherphuis makes some good additional points in [comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121401/find-the-object-from-its-shadows/121402#comment338651_121402) [below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121401/find-the-object-from-its-shadows/121402#comment338653_121402) this post...

> Namely that this is not the *only* object that satisfies this property, and others with smaller volumes can be constructed - for instance, by laying a horizontal circular base board and positioning two intersecting vertical boards - one triangular and one square - on top.

Comment: That's correct and incredibly fast!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky it is a bit known 3d graph :) that could be the reason. but still fast solution!

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I think I came across this in a book once before! Something clicked immediately when I saw your post...

Comment: Strictly speaking this answer gives only the largest object with those three shadows. You could cut away quite a lot of the volume without affecting those shadows, until you are left with three thin flat boards - a horizontal circular base board and a two vertical intersecting triangle and square boards on top. There are also other ways to cut a way that volume.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis True. My answer assumes it is a solid object all the way through (in the same way as a cube, tetrahedron or sphere would be).

Comment: @Stiv If you restrict yourself to convex shapes, I think it would still be possible shave off a little bit along that curved edge. If I'm imagining this correctly, the two curved side faces that resulted from the cylinder surface would become two [ruled surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface), each made from the straight lines connecting a top corner to any point on the base semicircle.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I've worked out where I know this from - it's in another form: an object fitting into three differently shaped holes rather than casting 3 different shadows, but it's the same solution ultimately, just a different scenario. It's [Puzzle 70 'The Peculiar Peg'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cxek.jpg) in Alex Bellos's book, *So You Think You've Got Problems?* (2019)

Comment: @Stiv I was reminded of another book in the same fashion as you: ["Gödel, Escher, Bach" by Douglas R. Hofstadter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach). On its cover, it features the same view of an object floating there, casting shadows on the wall.