# Find all the objects from their shadows

Tags: three-dimensional

In my previous [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121401/find-the-object-from-its-shadows) I asked you to derive the 3D object that casts 3 different shadows: circle, square and an equilateral triangle.

This is a more general version of the puzzle. If we limit ourselves to those three types of shadows then there are another 9 possible combinations:

1. Square, square, square
2. Square, square, circle
3. Square, square, triangle
4. Circle, circle, square
5. Circle, circle, circle
6. Circle, circle, triangle
7. Triangle, triangle, square
8. Triangle, triangle, circle
9. Triangle, triangle, triangle

Which of these shadow combinations have an associated 3D object and what is that object?

Comment: If the same basic shape appears two or three times as a shadow, do you require that the shadows are the same size? I think I can build a non-regular tetrahedron where all three shadows are equilateral triangles, but they will not be of the same size.

Comment: @quarague I would prefer them to be the same size, but if this is not possible then same shape would be fine.

Comment: Would this work?  Start with the following solid, a cube.  Then for every circular or triangular shadow desired, intersect the solid with a circular or triangular prism in the appropriate direction.

Comment: @Will Yep! The result will mostly look like my answer except you'll get a [tricylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid) for circle x circle x circle, what Wikipedia calls ["dual of triangular cupola"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneahedron) for triangle x triangle x triangle, and a cylinder/pyramid hybrid for triangle x triangle x circle. [(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sesUH.png)

Comment: @2012rcampion So my method works but it doesn’t generate the most elegant solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> 1. Cube
> 2. Cylinder
> 3. Triangular prism
> 4. Intersection of two cylinders at right angles
> 5. Sphere
> 6. Intersection of 3. and 4.
> 7. Pyramid
> 8. Cone
> 9. Tetrahedron (not regular, 3 sides have length $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}$ and the rest have length $\sqrt{15-8\sqrt{3}})$

3D view:

> [image: isometric view]

Columns:

> [image: front view]

Rows:

> [image: side view]

Top-down view:

> [image: top view]

Comment: Absolutely awesome answer!

Comment: A tetrahedron build out of equilateral triangles will **not** create shadows that are equilateral triangles from 3 perpendicular directions. The shadows will be triangles but not equilateral ones because you see the faces of the tetrahedron at different angles. I think you can build a tetrahedron that gives equilateral triangle shadows from all three directions but this requires more work.

Comment: Number six doesn't cast an equilateral triangle shadow

Comment: Some good points. So I am going to remove the tick for now. Feel free to add answers to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Note that A regular tetrahedron can have 3 square shadows.

Comment: I think the previous issues have been resolved now. Good job.